# Как сделать, чтобы EditText не накладывалась на другую?

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

Как сделать чтобы Address не выходил за границы и не накладывался на другой ??

Comment: можно просто добавить `android:singleLine="true"` в этот `edittext` (XML)

Comment: Можно код xml, пожалуйста, если добавите, просьба написать ответный комментарий